# Apple Mach-O linker error: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I'm fairly new to the coding world but I've been picking up on things real quick. However, this issue has me beat - I've tried looking through several forums to find out what the problem is but so far no dice. I keep getting two linker errors when ONY when I try to run an app on my device - it works fine in the simulator with no errors. Here's the log:

```
undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_NewBase64Encode", referenced from:
      -[NSData(Base64) base64EncodedString] in nsdata_and_base64.o
  "_NewBase64Decode", referenced from:
  +[NSData(Base64) dataFromBase64String:] in nsdata_and_base64.o
  _checkReceiptSecurity in verification_controller.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone got any ideas as to what the problem may be? Help would be much appreciated..

Thanks!!

Comment: check whether you have added the correct libraries in the Link Binary With Libraries section of the Build Phases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using lib that is compiled for simulator (i386 architecture).
You need find lib or build it if you have source code for iOS device.
BTW: NSData supports base64 encoding:
`- (NSString *)base64Encoding` Availability: iOS 4 - iOS 7;
`- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)options` Availability: iOS 7 and later.
May be you needn't use external lib at all.

Comment: Yep! it turns I was using frameworks I didn't need. Hence, several lines of code weren't needed either. So, I removed the libraries and code and it worked! Thanks Visput!